# Open URL on right click with selected text

Tags: windows-10, contextmenu, microsoft-teams

Running Windows 10 & MS Teams

I am looking for a hack that will allow me to open a web site with the selected text concatenated to the end of the URL.

I work on a team and I get messages in MS Teams all the time asking me about ticket 23423. I would like to add a context menu in MS Teams that would allow me to select the ticked #, right click, select 'Open Ticket' & launch a preset URL.

So in the example above, the URL launched would be **http://TicketSystem.domain.com?ID=23423**

Note - I do not have access to any of the admin features of MS Teams.

Comment: Hi @larryr, could you please confirm how you want your URL to be launched? As a tab in Teams or outside Teams?

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: In what ever the default browser is.